# Understanding find volume

Tags: calculus

1. $y=2\sqrt x$, from $x=1$ to $x=9$; rotating $x$
2. $y=2\sqrt x$, from $x=1$ to $x=9$; rotating $x=9$
3. $y=2\sqrt x$, from $x=1$ to $x=9$; rotating $y$
4. $y=2\sqrt x$, from $x=1$ to $x=9$; rotating $y=6$

My answer:

1. $\pi \int _{1}^{4}\left( 3\sqrt {x}\right) ^{2}dx$
2. $\pi \int _{1}^{4}\left( (3\sqrt {x})^2-(3)^2\right) dx$
3. $\pi \int _{1}^{4}(\dfrac {y^{2}} {6})^2dy$
4. $\pi \int _{1}^{4}(\dfrac {y^{2}} {6})^2-(3)^2dy$

**Can you check my answer? Can you help for question?**

Comment: I don't understand, for 2, how do you rotate that curve from $x=1$ to $x=4$, about $x=3$?

Comment: @peterwhy edited